# Getting code and setting up system, as well as writing code

Tags: android, ubuntu, installation

I need help on setting up my system to develop the Android OS (not apps the OS). I have an Ubuntu machine running 10.10, but I'm stuck on preparing my system and actually getting the code. What programs do I use? And what kind of things do I need to type to write the code?

Answer (score 2):

This [handy guide](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) will walk you through setting up your system.

In general, you will need to install:

- Git
- Python 2.4
- JDK 5 (froyo or older) or JDK 6 (gingerbread or newer)

> What programs do I use?

[Eclipse](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) seems to be the most popular IDE for working with Android.  Personally, I like using a plain old editor (emacs, vi, kate, etc.) and a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setup:

- Android SDK unzipped to ~/sdk/
- Add ~/sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools and ~/sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools to your path:

  echo "PATH=$PATH:~/sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools:~/sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools" >> ~/.profile
- install sun-java6-jdk. first enable the partner repository.

  sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
- install ant

  sudo apt-get install ant
- you'll have to choose an editor.  if you like gedit, I suggest adding the ubuntu-on-rails ppa (http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/get-textmate-features-and-styles-in.html) and installing gedit-gmate.  if you're a vim person, I suggest install vim-scripts

To support your real phone you may need to create a udev rules file.  Google 'android ubuntu udev your-phone-model' for help.  For instance, for a nexus one you would:
- add /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules with one line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18D1", MODE="0666"
```

After all of that, http://android.developer.com is your best friend.